# Facebook API Search - Search for Groups?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-group

I have been testing the Facebook php sdk. I am able to search for pages & places but not groups. According to the documentation, this should return groups...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=programming&type=group
```

The below code works. If I change the type from "page" to "group", the code fails. I do not get an exception:

```
$query = urlencode('Harlem');

$type = 'page';


$results = $facebook->api('/search?q='.$query.'&type='.$type);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on what kind of Access Token you're using. As of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/#access_tokens searches for pages require an App Access Token, whereas searches for Groups require an User Access Token. Please check accordingly.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I can't vote up due to a lack of 'reputation'.